# Unable to connect to FTP server using Filezilla with router in-between

Tags: ftp, wireless-router, filezilla, tls, ftps

While connecting to my web server using filezilla, i am getting this error:

```
Status: Resolving address of ftp.mysite.org.in
Status: Connecting to 199.199.199.18:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
Response:   220-You are user number 1 of 150 allowed.
Response:   220-Local time is now 17:58. Server port: 21.
Response:   220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
Response:   220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
Response:   220 You will be disconnected after 5 minutes of inactivity.
Command:    AUTH TLS
Response:   234 AUTH TLS OK.
Status: Initializing TLS...
Error:  GnuTLS error -9: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.
Status: Server did not properly shut down TLS connection
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

I use a cradlepoint CTR35 wifi router to connect to the wired internet connection.
When i connect to the same server without this router, the connection works flawlessly.

So i guess there is some problem with my router firewall settings, but i dont know what!
Can somebody help me out please?

**Note**: The server requires **EXPLICIT FTP OVER TLS** and does not work with plain FTP sessions. And i can connect to other servers using plain FTP with the router in between.

**EDIT:**

Okay. here is some debug info..

```
Status: Resolving address of ftp.md-47.webhostbox.net
Status: Connecting to 199.79.63.83:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
Response:   220-You are user number 1 of 150 allowed.
Response:   220-Local time is now 05:11. Server port: 21.
Response:   220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
Response:   220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
Response:   220 You will be disconnected after 5 minutes of inactivity.
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Command:    AUTH TLS
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   234 AUTH TLS OK.
Status: Initializing TLS...
Trace:  CTlsSocket::Handshake()
Trace:  CTlsSocket::ContinueHandshake()
Trace:  CTlsSocket::ContinueHandshake()
Trace:  CTlsSocket::ContinueHandshake()
Error:  GnuTLS error -9: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.
Status: Server did not properly shut down TLS connection
Trace:  CTlsSocket::OnSocketEvent(): close event received
Trace:  CRealControlSocket::OnClose(10053)
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(66)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(66)
Error:  Could not connect to server
Status: Waiting to retry...
```

Comment: Does your webhost support SSH?  If so, install WinSCP and use that.

Answer (score 0):

Which mode have you got FileZilla setup for, Active or Passive?

Active doesn't work (easily) behind a NAT router.

For more info, see the FileZila wiki entry [here](http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Network_Configuration#Setting_up_and_testing_FileZilla_Server):

> **Active mode**
>
> In active mode, the client opens a socket and waits for the server to
>   establish the transfer connection.   By default, FileZilla Client asks
>   the operating system for the machine's IP address and for the number
>   of a free port. *This configuration can only work if you are connected to the internet directly without any NAT router*, and if you have set
>   your firewall to allow incoming connections on all ports greater than
>   1024.

Comment: I have tried both Active as well as Passive modes, but still the same problem!